# wxPython - Getting attribute from another class?

Tags: python, class, attributes, get, wxpython

I want to update the self.CreateStatusBar() in MainWindow from MainPanel. And update the self.textOutput in MainPanel from MainWindow.

Been reading alot, but still cant grasp it. Please help me. =)

```
import wx 

ID_EXIT = 110

class MainPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        self.buttonRun = wx.Button(self, label="Run")
        self.buttonRun.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnRun )
        self.buttonExit = wx.Button(self, label="Exit")
        self.buttonExit.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnExit)

        self.labelChooseRoot = wx.StaticText(self, label ="Root catalog: ") 
        self.labelScratchWrk = wx.StaticText(self, label ="Scratch workspace: ")
        self.labelMergeFile = wx.StaticText(self, label ="Merge file: ")

        self.textChooseRoot = wx.TextCtrl(self, size=(210, -1))
        self.textChooseRoot.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_UP, self.OnChooseRoot)
        self.textScratchWrk = wx.TextCtrl(self, size=(210, -1))
        self.textMergeFile = wx.TextCtrl(self, size=(210, -1))
        self.textOutput = wx.TextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.TE_READONLY)

        self.sizerF = wx.FlexGridSizer(3, 2, 5, 5)
        self.sizerF.Add(self.labelChooseRoot)  #row 1, col 1
        self.sizerF.Add(self.textChooseRoot)   #row 1, col 2
        self.sizerF.Add(self.labelScratchWrk)  #row 2, col 1
        self.sizerF.Add(self.textScratchWrk)   #row 2, col 2
        self.sizerF.Add(self.labelMergeFile)   #row 3, col 1
        self.sizerF.Add(self.textMergeFile)    #row 3, col 2

        self.sizerB = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizerB.Add(self.buttonRun, 1, wx.ALIGN_RIGHT|wx.ALL, 5)
        self.sizerB.Add(self.buttonExit, 0, wx.ALIGN_RIGHT|wx.ALL, 5)

        self.sizer1 = wx.BoxSizer()
        self.sizer1.Add(self.sizerF, 0, wx.ALIGN_RIGHT | wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 10)
        self.sizer1.Add(self.sizerB, 0, wx.ALIGN_RIGHT | wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL)

        self.sizer2 = wx.BoxSizer()
        self.sizer2.Add(self.textOutput, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)

        self.sizerFinal = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizerFinal.Add(self.sizer1, 0, wx.ALIGN_RIGHT | wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL)
        self.sizerFinal.Add(self.sizer2, 1, wx.ALIGN_RIGHT | wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL)

        self.SetSizerAndFit(self.sizerFinal)


    def OnChooseRoot(self, event):
        dlg = wx.DirDialog(self, "Choose a directory:", style=wx.DD_DEFAULT_STYLE)
        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            root_path = dlg.GetPath()
            self.textChooseRoot.SetValue(root_path)
        dlg.Destroy()

    def OnRun(self, event):
        #First check if any of the boxes is empty
        pass

    def OnExit(self, event):
        self.GetParent().Close()


class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="IndexGenerator", size=(430, 330), 
                          style=((wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE | wx.NO_FULL_REPAINT_ON_RESIZE | 
                                  wx.STAY_ON_TOP) ^ wx.RESIZE_BORDER))
        self.CreateStatusBar() 

        self.fileMenu = wx.Menu()
        self.fileMenu.Append(ID_EXIT, "E&xit", "Exit the program")
        self.menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
        self.menuBar.Append(self.fileMenu, "&File")
        self.SetMenuBar(self.menuBar)
        wx.EVT_MENU(self, ID_EXIT, self.OnExit)                    

        self.Panel = MainPanel(self)

        self.CentreOnScreen()
        self.Show()

    def OnExit(self,  event):
        self.Close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MainWindow()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with AJ. You shouldn't modify GUI elements from each other directly. That ties things together pretty tightly. Instead, you should use something like pubsub or maybe wx.PostEvent to communicate between classes. Here's a simple pubsub example: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/06/27/wxpython-and-pubsub-a-simple-tutorial/

Comment: Man I love this site! =) Thanks Mike! Pubsub did the trick! =)) Is this what you generally use? This is the best way right? =)

Comment: Yes, it's what I normally use. There are similar modules you can use too, but I can't remember their names. Besides, pubsub is handier since it's included with wx. I think it's the best way, but others may find another method that they like better.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, **UI elements shouldn't directly modify one another**.  In an event-driven application, UI elements can listen for events, and then perform some action following the event.  Example: if the user does something to element B, element A can be notified of the event and then take an action.

Read more about events in wxPython here:

http://wiki.wxpython.org/AnotherTutorial#Events

Comment: Thanks for the link AJ. I'll read me up on wxPython with this. However I went for the pubsub provided by Mike. It seemd like the simplest thing to do. =) What do you reckon?

Comment: @sekstiseks - pubsub is a good way to implement this.  it creates a sort of "message bus" in your application for allowing multiple event listeners to subscribe to an event publisher/type.  good choice.

Answer (score 0):

In MainWindow:

```
self.Panel.textOutput.SetValue("...")
```

In MainPanel:

```
wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
self.window = parent 
self.window.SetStatusText("...")
```